# How to show Nested Collection in Xamarin.Forms ListView

Tags: listview, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Guys, I am new to xamarin.forms and trying to show Quiz as nested ListView inside my xamarin.forms where Question and it's associated options will be shown but I am not able to show this list Properly in listview so if anyone have any idea how can i do this please help me..that will be great help

here is my code

```
    public QuizViewModel(int testId)
    {
        var quizModel = Load(testId);
        QuizList = new ObservableCollection<QuizModel>(quizModel);
    }



    public List<QuizModel> Load(int testId)
    {
            List<Suggestions> suggestionlist;
            List<QuizModel> quizList = new List<QuizModel>();
            var responseString = CommonFunctions.GetQuestionItems(testId);
            var responseData = JArray.Parse(responseString.ToString());
            var Questions = new List<QuizModel>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var quiz in responseData)
            {
                i++;
                suggestionlist = new List<Suggestions>();

                var ques = new QuizModel
                {

                    QuestionNumber = i,
                    Id = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quiz["Id"].ToString()) ? (int)quiz["Id"] : 0,
                    TestId = testId,
                    Question = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quiz["Title"].ToString()) ? quiz["Title"].ToString() : string.Empty,
                    Answer = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quiz["Answer"].ToString()) ? quiz["Answer"].ToString() : string.Empty,
                    UserSelectedAnswer = string.Empty,
                };
                suggestionlist.Add(new Model.Suggestions { Option = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quiz["OptionA"].ToString()) ? quiz["OptionA"].ToString() : string.Empty });
                suggestionlist.Add(new Model.Suggestions { Option = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quiz["OptionB"].ToString()) ? quiz["OptionB"].ToString() : string.Empty });
                suggestionlist.Add(new Model.Suggestions { Option = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quiz["OptionC"].ToString()) ? quiz["OptionC"].ToString() : string.Empty });
                suggestionlist.Add(new Model.Suggestions { Option = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(quiz["OptionD"].ToString()) ? quiz["OptionD"].ToString() : string.Empty });
                ques.Suggestions = suggestionlist;

                Questions.Add(ques);

            }

            return Questions;
        }
```

Quiz model :

```
public class QuizModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public List<Suggestions> Suggestions { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string UserSelectedAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

here is my xaml code:

```
<ScrollView >
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding QuizList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="{Binding Question}" TextColor="White"/>
      </StackLayout>
       <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <ViewCell.View>
                     <StackLayout Padding="10">
                       <Frame>
                         <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Option}"/>
                          </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                      </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                   </ViewCell>
                 </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
              </ListView>
            <DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate> 
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding QuizList}"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        IsGroupingEnabled="True"
        GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"  >
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
     <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            Text="{Binding Key}" 
            TextColor="Red"/>        
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>        
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Frame Padding="10">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Option}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Make your Question answer list in key value format using Dictionary and then just bind that list in xaml page.( Key as your name of variable for Question and value as your option).